# Discord Bot Automated Kick with no user interaction

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots

I am in process of writing a bot that will initiate a kick sequence when a message is received on a certain channel. It compares data on a Google Sheet to find the user ID of a member who previously verified a subscription, but has now cancelled. Everything is working up to the point of using the `await bot.kick()` coroutine. I have even attempted to define another function to call in order to complete this.

I have read over the API documentation to no avail. My other option is to strip the subscribed access role and leave it to the user to leave the server or assign a different role and create an admin command that will have to be ran occasionally to kick those with that role.

```py
@bot.event
@bot_has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def on_message(message):
    channel_rcv = channel_autoIO
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_track)
    if message.channel.id == channel_rcv:
        print("This worked")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await message.delete()
        await channel.send("User kick initiated")
        cell_tag = wks.find(unsubTag)
        if bool(cell_tag) == True:
            cell_tagadd = wks.cell(cell_tag[0].label)
            cell_left = cell_tagadd.neighbour('left')
            email = cell_left.value
            cell_list = wks_2.find(email)
            cell_address = cell_list[0].label
            cell_email = wks_2.cell(cell_address)
            cell_adj = cell_email.neighbour('left')
            cell_user = cell_adj.value
            print(cell_user)
            await channel.send("Kicking: " + cell_user)
            await bot.kick(cell_user, reason = "User unsubscribed")
        else:
            await channel.send("Error: Unsubscribed user not found. Please perform a manual verification and report discrepancies to @Developer")
    else:
        return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more investigation and asking a few questions on the Discord.py server, I was able to solve my issue!

```py
user_id = discord.Object(id = message.guild.get_member_named(cell_name).id)
await message.guild.kick(user_id, reason = cell_name + reason)
```

I utilized the `discord.Object` to pull the member ID from the username stored on the Google Sheet I am using for tracking purposes. This allow me to not need to specify an author or member as this function is not a user entered command.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually `await message.author.kick(cell_user, reason = "User unsubscribed")` **not** `await bot.kick(cell_user, reason = "User unsubscribed")`.

`message.author.kick()`: kicks the member who sent the message inside `channel_rcv`.

`bot.kick()`: attemps to kick the bot.

Comment: Actually I have tried that format and it provides this:

`AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'member'`

So that actually doesn't work.

Comment: My bad, it's `message.author`, not `message.member`.